# Qu'est-ce que c'est la forme emphatique?

Tags: phrase

Dans un livre scolaire de grammaire de ma nièce, il y a des exercices sur des types de phrases (déclaratif, interrogatif, forme emphatique).

Cette forme emphatique est quelque chose de nouveau pour moi (je ne la connais pas en allemand ou en anglais). Qu'est-ce que c'est alors ce type de phrase ? Pourquoi cette forme n'est-elle pas connue dans d'autres langues ?

Comment: https://www.jerevise.fr/phrase-forme-emphatique-neutre-francais.html, http://www.alloprof.qc.ca/BV/pages/f1140.aspx, https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-13120.php, https://www.maxicours.com/se/cours/les-formes-de-phrase-affirmative-negative-et-emphatique/, https://www.lelivrescolaire.fr/manuel/1374088/cahier-dexercices-francais-3e/chapitre/1374123/grammaire/page/1374468/11-types-et-formes-de-phrase/lecon/document/5912577. English has emphatic do (I **do** love cakes.)

Comment: J'ai trouvé ce lien qui me semble utile : https://www.jerevise.fr/phrase-forme-emphatique-neutre-francais.html

Comment: Empathique =/= emphatique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cette forme existe bien en anglais et elle vous est certainement familière. Il suffit d'ajouter l'auxiliaire « do » ou de l'accentuer lorsqu'il apparait déjà en raison de la forme interrogative ou négative ; à l'écrit on souligne l'auxiliaire ou on le met en italique et dans la langue parlée on utilise l'accent de phrase sur l'auxiliaire. Cependant, si cet aspect de l'emphase (emphasis) en anglais est fondamental (https://www.grammaring.com/the-auxiliaries-do-and-does-for-emphasis), ce n'est pas le seul (https://www.ecenglish.com/en/social/blog/san-francisco/2011/11/28/grammar-lesson-inversion-and-emphasis). En français, de même, l'emphase est ce qui réfère à un ensemble de constructions qui permettent d'insister sur ce qui est dit et il existe un ensemble de constructions aussi mais la construction anglaise qui introduit un auxiliaire n'existe pas.

- The sun **does** move from east to west in the sky.
- You **do** have to know that or you can't go further.

Dans ces deux cas un moyen de traduire la forme emphatique consiste à utiliser des adverbes.

- Le soleil se déplace **bien** d'est en ouest dans le ciel.
- Vous devez **vraiment** savoir cela sinon vous ne pouvez pas continuer.

Les pages web suivantes fournissent des informations de base sur la syntaxe de l'emphase et peuvent être un complément utile.

http://www.alloprof.qc.ca/BV/pages/f1140.aspx
https://www.jerevise.fr/phrase-forme-neutre-emphatique-francais.html

Answer (score 1):

Après avoir fait un googling on dispose de pas mal de sources scolaires.
 Ex.
http://www.alloprof.qc.ca/BV/pages/f1140.aspx

> La phrase emphatique est une phrase dans laquelle un élément est mis
>   en relief, ce qui crée un effet d'insistance sur cet élément. Elle
>   s'oppose à la forme neutre de la phrase de base.

[Grevisse-collège](https://books.google.fr/books?id=D_i1DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=forme%20empathique%20grevisse&source=bl&ots=F_O1DR2Y-C&sig=ACfU3U0qOb9BGalyP6u9SWSI-cJ4Jkvg3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi94OKer4bmAhUSXxoKHRUKCXIQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=forme%20empathique%20grevisse&f=false)

[En anglais on emploie aussi le verbe auxiliaire « do » dans le même but. 
https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-emphatic-do-1690590 ]